# Combine two MySQL views into one view

Tags: mysql, view

I have two working MySQL views:

First view selects all rows from table `portfolio` which id's are in table `mural` as well.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_mural` AS
    select 
        `portfolio`.`id`                    AS `id`,
        `portfolio`.`customer_id`           AS `customer_id`,
        `portfolio`.`location_id`           AS `location_id`,
        `portfolio`.`title_text_id`         AS `title_text_id`,
        `portfolio`.`description_text_id`   AS `description_text_id`,
        `portfolio`.`started`               AS `started`,
        `portfolio`.`finished`              AS `finished`,
    from
        `portfolio`
    where
        `portfolio`.`id` in (select 
                `mural`.`portfolio_id`
            from
                `mural`) WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION
```

Second view selects rows from two tables: `portfolio` and `mural`.

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `view_mural` AS
    select 
        `portfolio`.`id`                                AS `id`,
        `portfolio`.`customer_id`                       AS `customer_id`,
        `portfolio`.`location_id`                       AS `location_id`,
        `portfolio`.`title_text_id`                     AS `title_text_id`,
        `portfolio`.`description_text_id`               AS `description_text_id`,
        `portfolio`.`started`                           AS `started`,
        `portfolio`.`finished`                          AS `finished`,
        (select 
            `mural`.`width` 
        from 
            `mural` 
        where 
            `mural`.`portfolio_id`=`portfolio`.`id`)    AS `mup`
    from
        `portfolio`
```

I can't get, how to combine these into one view, to select table, with columns from both tables, which contains rows from table portfolio which id's are in table mural as well.

When I add:

```
    where
        `portfolio`.`id` in (select 
                `mural`.`portfolio_id`
            from
                `mural`) WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION
```

to the very end of my second view it shows me an error:

```
Apply changes to view_mural Error 1368: CHECK OPTION on non-updatable view 'view_mural' SQL Statement:  CREATE       OR REPLACE ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED      DEFINER = `root`@`localhost`      SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_mural` AS     select          `portfolio`.`id` AS `id`,         `portfolio`.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,         `portfolio`.`location_id` AS `location_id`,         `portfolio`.`title_text_id` AS `title_text_id`,         `portfolio`.`description_text_id` AS `description_text_id`,         `portfolio`.`started` AS `started`,         `portfolio`.`finished` AS `finished`,         (select `mural`.`width` from `mural` where `mural`.`portfolio_id`=`portfolio`.`id`) AS `mup`     from         `portfolio`     where         `portfolio`.`id` in (select                  `mural`.`portfolio_id`             from                 `mural`) WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION  Error when running failback script. Details follow. Error 1050: Table 'view_mural' already exists SQL Statement: CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_mural` AS select `portfolio`.`id` AS `id`,`portfolio`.`customer_id` AS `customer_id`,`portfolio`.`location_id` AS `location_id`,`portfolio`.`title_text_id` AS `title_text_id`,`portfolio`.`description_text_id` AS `description_text_id`,`portfolio`.`started` AS `started`,`portfolio`.`finished` AS `finished`,(select `mural`.`width` from `mural` where ((`mural`.`portfolio_id` = `portfolio`.`id`) and `portfolio`.`id` in (select `mural`.`portfolio_id` from `mural`))) AS `mup` from `portfolio`
```

Could someone point me how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```
SELECT
    portfolio.id,
    portfolio.customer_id,
    portfolio.location_id,
    portfolio.title_text_id,
    portfolio.description_text_id,
    portfolio.started,
    portfolio.finished,
    mural.width
FROM
    portfolio JOIN mural ON mural.portfolio_id = portfolio.id
```